# is ordering processes in ascending run time, an optimal way to create a set of non overlapping processes?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, time, greedy

there are n jobs in a set, each with starting times s<sub>i</sub>, and finish times f<sub>i</sub>, for n<sub>i</sub>

I'm trying to figure out if the ordering jobs in ordering ascending start time, finish time, and interval time (f<sub>i</sub> - s<sub>i</sub>) is optimal or not.

I said that ordering in ascending earliest start time was not optimal in the case that the first job starts first however spans the time that 3 jobs could be started and finished.

Next I said that ordering in ascending finish time was optimal because right when a finish time is added, the next fastest ending job as added, maximizing numbers of jobs added to the non-overlapping jobs list.

However I'm not sure about the ordering f<sub>i</sub> - s<sub>i</sub> is optimal.

My logic is that it is optimal, because it would list the shortest jobs which I believe would add or consider the jobs that span the lengths of other jobs last

EDIT : Optimize by maximizing the size of the non-overlapping processes list

Comment: It is hard to tell if something is optimal when "optimal" is left undefined. What is your objective function? What are your constraints?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to maximize numbers of jobs added to the set.

Comment: What does it mean to "add a job to a set"? How does "adding a job" relate to "ordering" a job? You aren't defining your terms.

Comment: Okay I re read what I typed and I really left out a lot of details; there is a list of n jobs, each with its own start and finish time. I want to create a sub set of jobs, where each job does not have its start and finish time overlap with another job. I.E. We can't do 2 jobs at once. I want to have maximal jobs in this subset

Comment: @DanNguyen one of the things that keeps the community here running is the appreciation of efforts by giving points. you might consider also "giving points" to others by marking answers as useful, especially for answers to your questions (then you can also accept one of the answers as the one solving the question for you)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a suprisingly simple strategy for choosing the next job which gives you a subset with the maximal number of consecutive jobs: **among the jobs left which have a valid start time** (in the beginning: all start times are valid; after the first job has been chosen the start time of the next job must, of course, not precede the finish time of the previously chosen job) **always choose the job with the earliest finish time**.

A proof that this strategy is optimal can start like this: assume you have an optimal (i.e. maximal) subset of consecutive jobs and that the first job is not the job with the (overall) earliest finish time, then this job with the overall earliest finish time cannot be in the optimal subset, but you can replace the first job of the optimal subset with this job and you get another optimal subset which has the job with earliest finish time as first job. Now you can continue in the same way with the second job and thus it is clear that in the subset generated with the above strategy the n-th job has a finish time that does not exceed the finish time of the n-th job of any optimal subset, for any n, and hence the so created subset is also optimal.

Comment: Nice proof. I was skeptical at first since the problem reminded me too much of a knapsack problem but then I realized it would be like a knapsack problem where the values of the objects are all the same and you are just trying to maximize the number of chosen objects. If I am not mistaken, OP would have an NP-hard problem if they wanted to maximize the % of time which was utilized.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks. This was a "flash" when I read the question. I have some practical experience in combinatorial optimization, but I am not so much into the theory. The % of utilized time is often a more practical criterion, but (much) harder to optimize for. Sorry, that's all I can say.